# Ionic5 npm ERR whith ionic cordova platform add android command

Tags: npm, ionic5

## Summary of the problem

I have a mobile application project in Ionic5. I have successfully run the command `npm install`, but when I run  `ionic cordova platform add android` I have this error :

```
sudo ionic cordova platform add android 
> cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
CordovaError: Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install cordova-android --save-dev
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/animations@10.2.5
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"9.1.13" from @angular/common@9.1.13
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!       @angular/fire@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"9.1.13" from @angular/forms@9.1.13
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=8.2.7" from @ionic/angular@5.9.4
npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!     4 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"^9.0.0 || ^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0" from @angular/fire@6.1.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!     @angular/fire@"^6.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   8 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"10.2.5" from @angular/animations@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^10.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"10.2.5" from @angular/animations@10.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!     @angular/animations@"^10.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

## My environment & package.json

MacOS Ventura

NodeJs v18.16.0

Npm 9.6.7

Ionic -v : 7.1.1

Dependencies of Package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.45.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/market": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^5.27.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "compare-func": "^2.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "~7.0.0",
    "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "github:mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "github:mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.15.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter": "^1.1.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.4",
    "@angular/cli": "10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.2.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.8"
  },
```

## What I tried

- I tried different versions of Angular, NodeJs and Ionic ...
- I had completely uninstall all npm package and Node Js
- Deleted package.json
- Deleted node_module directory
- Clean npm cache
- Re-run npm install (successfuly again)

But same probleme ...

I have no idea why it finds `@angular/core@9.1.13` when the installed version is `~10.2.5`

if anyone has an idea it will save my day :D

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

It's written in your error log ionic/angular 5.9.4 - have angular/core v 9.*.* as peer dependency.

So try to use npm i --force or short npm i -f
& ionic cordova platform add android --force

1. Delete node_modules folder
2. Delete platforms folder - Read the note below
3. Delete plugins folder
4. Delete package-lock.json file
   If you use a global cordova installation, then do: npm uninstall -g cordova && npm install -g cordova
5. run npm install --force
6. run cordova platform add android --force

Let me know if these steps are not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I tried your solution but I got the same error.

Comment: @DrZoedberg - try to downgrade your node version. Install v15

Comment: 'I tried different versions of Angular, NodeJs and Ionic' - hm so you already tried it? after installing this version of node try to follow all those steps...

Comment: Yes, when i tried "ionic cordova platform add android", I had the error "ERR: Your Node.js version is v15.14.0. Please update to the latest Node LTS version."

Comment: Well, after installing NodeJs V15 then re-installing V18 and overwriting the "platforms" folder from an old backup, it works!

I don't understand why, but it works...

Thank you very much @Eugene_Kr